# How to generate wireframe from point clouds on top of observed objects

Tags: mesh, orb, wireframe, slam

Iam trying to generate wireframe on top of objects after generating the point clouds. How can i get wireframes similar to the ones generated in the image?

I am able to run ORB SLAM2 and generate point clouds and save them. Iam even able to generate wireframe from .pcd files from the point cloud library. 
However Iam looking for results such as the ones shown in this picture. 
How can i approach towards this?

[The target wireframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlG1V.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORB-SLAM 2 is at its heart just a sparse feature-based SLAM. What you want can't be achieved with just that library, and furthermore, the image you give as an example is reprojecting a CDI mesh into the image. The only way you can get results like this is by having a 3D mesh of the object before you run your SLAM, and localise said mesh in the scene (there is a vast litterature on model-based SLAM, which I think is the best place for you to look into). The main idea in that case would be to match elements from the 3d mesh to elements in the image (whethere those are keypoints or some form of features), and use them either in your cost function or in some PnP-like scheme.